# How can I install the standalone ember router?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ember-router

I'm having trouble installing this -> https://github.com/tildeio/router.js in my MVC project.

I first just loaded these two scripts:

```
vendor/deps/route-recognizer.js
dist/router.js
```

Added the line:

```
var router = new Router();
```

I ended up with the following console errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined ***route-recognizer.js:1***
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined ***router.js:2084***
Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined
```

I then loaded these scripts:

```
vendor/loader.js
vendor/deps/backburner.js
vendor/deps/rsvp.js
vendor/deps/route-recognizer.js
dist/router.js
```

I get these errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined ***router.js:2084***
Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined
```

This is code where the 'Promise' error occurs:

```
   define("route-recognizer", [], function() { return {"default": RouteRecognizer}; });
   define("rsvp", [], function() { return RSVP;});
-->define("rsvp/promise", [], function() { return {"default": RSVP.Promise}; });
```

Is there a promise.js I need as well? I found a promise.js in the RSVP.js package but loading gives me another error.

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same problem.

There seem to be a code change according to [this post](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/issues/100) for `router.js` to work as a standalone.

Grab the laters [rsvp](http://rsvpjs-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/rsvp-latest.js), [route-recognizer](https://github.com/tildeio/route-recognizer/blob/master/dist/route-recognizer.js) and [router](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/blob/master/dist/router.min.js) and create a router object like so

```
<script src="routerjs/rsvp-latest.js"></script>
<script src="routerjs/route-recognizer.js"></script>
<script src="routerjs/router.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var router = new Router["default"]();
</script>
```